# Select unique XElements (by attribute) using LinqToXml

Tags: xml, linq-to-xml, xelement, xattribute

I have a XML where I have several `<testcase>` tags. Some of them have attribute "ident" with value "pr", some not.

```
<testcase>
  <teststep ident="Preparation" result="na">blabla</teststep>
  <teststep ident="" result="pass">blabla</teststep>
  <teststep ident="-" result="na">blabla</teststep>
  <teststep ident="Info" result="na">blabla</teststep>
  <teststep ident="1" result="pass">blabla</teststep>
  <teststep ident="2" result="pass">blabla</teststep>
  <teststep ident="3" result="pass">blabla</teststep>
  <teststep ident="4" result="fail">blabla</teststep>
  <teststep ident="PR" result="na">blabla</teststep>
  <verdict result="fail" />
</testcase>
```

I would like to query testcases which contains ident attribute with value "pr"

```
IEnumerable<XElement> failedPRTCs = report.Descendants("testcase").Where(t => t.Element("verdict").Attribute("result").Value == "fail" && t.Descendants("teststep").Where(ts=> ts.Attribute("ident").Value == "pr").ToList().Count > 0).ToList();
```

Current query returns 0. Whats the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a simple problem of casing! `"pr"` vs `"PR"`! I would also recommend using `Any` rather than `count > 0`:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> failedPRTCs = report.Descendants("testcase")
    .Where(t => t.Element("verdict").Attribute("result").Value == "fail" &&
           t.Descendants("teststep").Any(ts=> ts.Attribute("ident").Value == "PR"));
```

Comment: Yes, thanks :) I really did simple mistake.. lowercased "pr" instead of "PR". And thanks for advice regarding Any keyword